# Cant install atop on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i have dockerfile with command to run install atop but, i dont know why i am getting error
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt install atop' returned a non-zero code: 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvMWR.png)

this is my Dockerfile

```
 FROM timbru31/java-node

RUN apt update
RUN apt install atop 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-interactive installation. And you can do that on one RUN execution.

```
RUN apt update && \
  apt install -y atop
```